# Differentiating Landau free energy functional from the energy levels of a system

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, partition-function

I quote from Huang's [Introduction to Statistical Mechanics](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Introduction_to_Statistical_Physics_Seco.html?id=bVjNBQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) (not the book Statistical Mechanics), page 266

> Consider, for simplicity, a one-component order parameter, a scalar field $\phi(x)$ over a space of any number of dimensions. The state of the system is specified by $\phi(x)$, and the statistical ensemble describing the thermal properties of the system is a set of such fields, with assigned statistical weights given by the Boltzmann factor $$e^{-\beta E[\phi]}$$ where $\beta=(k_BT)^{-1}$. The functional $E[\phi]$, called the *Landau free energy* specifies the system.

Then in order to calculate the partition function $Q$ he used (in Eq. (19.4)) the following functional integral $$Q=\int D\phi e^{-\beta E[\phi]}\tag{1}$$ which appears to be the generalization of the canonical partition function formula  $$Z=\sum\limits_{\rm{states}~ j} e^{-\beta E_j}\tag{2}$$ in the limit when $j$ becomes a continuous label. Therefore, as far as I can understand, $E[\phi]$ is essentially same as the energy levels of the system $E_j$. However, according to Huang's description, $E[\phi],$ is called *Landau free energy*.

$\bullet$ But the energy levels $E_j$ in expression (2) is independent of temperature and is determined from the classical or quantum dynamics of the system. All temperature dependencies in $Z$ enter through the factor $\beta$.

$\bullet$ However, the *Landau free energy* $E[\phi]$ is postulated to be of the form $$
E[\phi]=\int d^dx\Big[\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}|\nabla\phi(x)|^2+W(\phi(x))-h(x)\phi(x)\Big]$$ where $$W(\phi(x))=g_2\phi^2(x)+g_3\phi^3(x)+g_4\phi^4(x)+...$$ where the coupling constants $g_n$ are the phenomenological parameter of the theory, and **may depend on the temperature**. Therefore, $E[\phi]$ can be temperature-dependent.

**Questions**

**A**. *Does it not mean that Landau free energy is different from the energy levels of the systems?*

**B**. *If yes, how can we use the formula (1) by generalizing (2)?*

**C**. *There is another possibility that $E[\phi]$ is defined after some coarse-graining and therefore, has temperature dependence built into it apart from $\beta$. If that is the case, (1) is not a straightforward generalization of (2). Please enlighten me.*

Comment: It seems that Huang's generalization refers not to the replacement of the sum by an integral. The usual canonical sum can also be written in the form of an integral
$Z=\sum\limits_{\rm{states}~ j} e^{-\beta E_j}=\int \rho{(E)}e^{-\beta E}dE=\int e^{-\beta F}$, where $\rho{(E)}$ is a density of enrgy states.Free energy in this case: $F=(-ln(\rho(E))/\beta)+E$

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist As Thomas says, and as also I conjectured, there is a coarse-graining involved in going from (2) to (1). But I don't understand how does coarse-graining make $E[\phi]$ temperature dependent.

Comment: Analogically in case of *functional* $E[\phi]$ we have $F[\phi]=\int dx(-s(x)/\beta)+\epsilon(x))=\int f(x, \beta) dx$,  specific form of $ f (x, \beta) $ is given by the Landau theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is indeed a coarse grained version of (2). There are a number of ways of doing this, for example the renormalization group, or the mean field approximation.

Comment: My question is why should $E[\phi]$ depend on temperature while $E_j$ do not. @Thomas

Comment: @SRS You are performing the coarse graining at some temperature T, so the resulting functional $E[\phi]$ will naturally depend on T. Indeed, as Landau explains, this is really a free energy functional, not an energy functional.

Comment: But by coarse-graining, you mean something like the block-spin transformation of the microscopic Hamiltonian of the Ising model (for example). Right? I'm not getting how'll that introduced $T$. Well. Let me give it some more thought. @Thomas